# Cannot Import DWG file into QGIS

Tags: qgis, dwg

I have a DWG file that I want to open in QGIS. However, whenever I try to import it I keep getting this error message.

Is the problem possibly the geopackage, as it only has one blank table?

I also tried to open it using LibreCAD but I could not see the file when I navigated to the project folder.

[image]

Comment: It depends of the version of DWG you have. I suggest you to first convert your DWG to a DXF.

Comment: I converted the DWG to a DXF using an online convertor. When I tried to import it I get the same problem. I am suspecting that the problem is the projection system as an associated excel file has lat and long values in decimal degrees but they are definitely not WSG84.

Comment: is the dxf/dwg available online?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to share the file publicly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After converting from DWG to DXF, try with this plugin, and see if you get the same error: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: So if it works, please accept the response! Thank you